# Recursively transform all leafs of an object tree in typescript

Tags: typescript, tree

Given a simple object tree that either contains values of its own type or of a type that needs to be transformed:

```js
interface Tree<Leaf> {
  [key: string]: Tree<Leaf> | Leaf;
}
```

I want to define a function that recursively transforms all leafs to another type like this:

```js
function transformTree<S, T>(
  obj: Tree<S>,
  transform: (value: S) => T,
  isLeaf: (value: S | Tree<S>) => boolean
): Tree<T> {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    ...Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({
      [key]: isLeaf(value)
        ? transform(value as S)
        : transformTree(value as Tree<S>, transform, isLeaf),
    }))
  );
}
```

How do can I maintain the types of the leafs between the source tree and transformed tree?

Testing the above doesn't work:

```js
class Wrapper<T> {
  constructor(public value: T) {}
}

function transform<T>(wrapped: Wrapper<T>): T {
  return wrapped.value;
}

function unwrap<T>(wrapped: Tree<Wrapper<T>>): Tree<T> {
  return transformTree<Wrapper<T>, T>(
    wrapped,
    transform,
    (value: Wrapper<T> | Tree<Wrapper<T>>) => value instanceof Wrapper
  );
}

const obj = unwrap<string>({
  foo: {
    bar: new Wrapper("baz"),
  },
  cow: new Wrapper("moo"),
});

function handleBaz(value: "baz") {
  return true;
}

function handleMoo(value: "moo") {
  return true;
}

handleBaz(obj.foo.bar); // Error:(162, 19) TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'string | Tree<string>'. Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'string'.
handleMoo(obj.cow); //Error:(163, 11) TS2345: Argument of type 'string | Tree<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '"moo"'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"moo"'.
```

I can see that the error occurs, because the tree structure is not maintained through the transformation (the transformation only works at runtime). But given that the transformation is predictable given a known structure of the input tree, I feel that there should be a way to do this in typescript.

Here is my attempt to solve this:

```js
type TransformTree<Leaf, InputTree extends Tree<Leaf>, T> = {
  [K in keyof InputTree]: InputTree[K] extends Leaf
    ? T
    : InputTree[K] extends Tree<Leaf>
    ? TransformTree<Leaf, InputTree[K], T>
    : never;
};

type IsLeaf<Leaf> = (value: Tree<Leaf> | Leaf) => boolean;

function transformTree<T extends Tree<From>, From, To>(
  tree: T,
  transform: (value: From) => To,
  isLeaf: IsLeaf<From>
): TransformTree<From, typeof tree, To> {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    ...Object.entries(tree).map(([key, value]) => ({
      // XXX have to cast the value in each case, because typescript cannot predict
      // the outcome of isLeaf().
      [key]: isLeaf(value)
        ? transform(value as Extract<typeof tree[typeof key], From>)
        : transformTree(
            value as Extract<typeof tree[typeof key], Tree<From>>,
            transform,
            isLeaf
          ),
    }))
  );
}
```

It still doesn't seem to understand the nested types:

```js
function unwrap<T>(
  wrapped: Tree<Wrapper<T>>
): TransformTree<Wrapper<T>, typeof wrapped, T> {
  return transformTree(
    wrapped,
    transform,
    (value: Wrapper<T> | Tree<Wrapper<T>>) => value instanceof Wrapper
  );
}


function handleBaz(value: "baz") {
  return true;
}

function handleMoo(value: "moo") {
  return true;
}

handleMoo(obj.cow); // OK

handleBaz(obj.foo.bar); // TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThCAeAMhAhgMwHxQLxQDeAsAFBRQDaA1hCAFxQDOwcAlgHYDmAuo-IlQYcUAD5Q0WANxkAvjNJlQkWHHQcmmAPZwAtgOSTMAGigBJDmACuwA1AgAPYBA4ATJqsFHspmLgIk5FQA0lCcULQgWpjmljYGfLHWtggQlME89k4u7hLCZBQUAPywBYWMFskG6ZmOzm4eBkJY2GXFquqaOvqpzSZJ8ak1vq1BFIwcEABuEHAK8mRK4NBmTEZ9-lAAFFPoADZWEPy93mJ5WACU+LgARlpaexgcCmSYVhwAxsBsWhxQrJ1tHomjAsvVck0AGJwLS6HxQaGw3xabBbMqsRD8YzotQaIG6Rg7faHRiI3RXPC4GBabFBNhrYQVBlYJBk0YXY6A7pQmG6UzKCDRf6pZG4QIUBDAKxwP4AeRuACsIF8AHToJhMNhcDhosZEWS0wpQFUm+VK1UuVhsCBMLYYiAXFW6dBgLZbGh0Uy7A4QHgU3BbcVGqiRRL0oxEn0XNrBkoAvHdSOHKDqqAAUScai+SAFQvtlFzMVDpjZ0b1RsY8a6wNSuuD9ag3uTqYzAOzheFiALyyFxc8yDZPhjDeFXL0hpHhXD+XLwYuE4osguZYoF3mi1IHz26o8AHU1GBIHAkH4iGUPr8WHArF8dFtrDc9mwPo3iUdYFdCLI5Bu3p9vr8o4JnoJ6ogA7gekCuIw+4ukeoEcrAZ5BJK0p-BBcEQK4KpNhA66KKQf5fD8fzvBhYCgXWUDkVBxyCLBh6zKB7KcsBPT0ZBTF+PyPYxDRWEjMhEoQFKMpAdW7EQFRFD8a4C7ifi8lJu+DHwae4hNKpXHYNg-qvj6YQaMA6gfIKMRaXAZRrj+BEXkZUBaIq+BQGRB5IFenBcKiQbaFojBBhQNzoHAEwQGBUAWVsABEQUAF5RfOZQGueWhgaF4WRVFuj3AltJLi8hHvMRgEABbqK4jwAELoLFymMDFNUJUJUCoWJrCHPhrxFQBfxlW4jwALL3HVUBZTln5lK1fztXhNlkH1FUQENWhbI5CoqheYFrlAAD0O1QLKwQbgtVU1atioqr5KpBXA217bAADKABMADML0AJyMAACjCR6gFAADkN0A1ArhaDaUAcFowBZPSMOAQKgOTDMcAAyqZBAA)

It seems like typescript still thinks that if the field value is not a Leaf, then it may be something other than a sub-tree.

Comment: As soon as you assign a tree object to the type `Tree<X>` for some `X`, you lose the key structure.  So your `unwrap()` function is insufficiently generic since `wrapped` is of type `Tree<Wrapper<T>`.  This is surmountable.  But furthermore it looks like you are expecting the tree to remember each value type at each leaf node throughout the tree (since you are talking about literal `"baz"` and `"moo"` types.) This is unlikely to be solvable in general since the transformation would need to be generic and `TransformTree` would require a higher order type mapping and that doesn't exist in TS.

Comment: If you want to write the typing for `unwrap()` you can do it, but not using a general-purpose `TransformTree` type alias that does not itself mention `Wrapper` somewhere in its definition.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqBOYAOSCm8A8AVAfNA3gLABQ0Z0wA9gHYQAu8ArsHZfABRKMBGIAlsGgA3MCEaoAXNCwBKAtAC+JJcRJ0AnmmgBVagHdESbNFQAPOqmoATGJW4ArVCzwBeeQG0A0tD7VoAa1R1SgAzaQBdKSwvcJNzSxs4QzRMXxD0ODwAfjhoKJi4i2tbByc6aBzdA2RsGLx8z3CAbkUSKydweFRoEMZqFj4aaD7qoyxChJLHZ3Y6KJkpKsNsHCaSEipacrt7aDcRw3YiUnIQykopY-Jr6G4weClqVD0k5BT2ACI7gC8P6EgKDR6DIADQka4KMEnMhUPSPZ6vFDoT4AW3OfwBm2BUIUMjWqmIvX6dEGfgAFmBrCBUAAhMDfdgiMSSaBfekfOT4VqEvoDIYUqmoACy50ZonEUg+aMoHPkKgFVmpdIZOwAdGdKKq7vA8SQFdSRZR2GrYbqCetiEA).

Comment: Using literal types and that simple wrapper was just for the isolated example to post there. In the real application we are dealing with unions and different concretions of an abstract class.

Comment: Okay, so what do you want to see in an answer, then?  I'd love to write `TransformTree<OrigTree, Leaf, LeafTransformer>` and you'd use it like `TransformTree<typeof obj, Wrapper<any>, UnwrapLeaf>` with `type UnwrapLeaf<W extends Wrapper<any>> = W["value"]`, but that's not possible since `UnwrapLeaf` is not a type but a type function. Without [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) any tree transformer type function will need to be less abstract than you're hoping for here.  Can you narrow the scope to some more specific type of leaf transformation to support?

Comment: Ok, I understand, that is unfortunate that it is not possible to do what intended for. However I think your latest comment does qualify as an acceptable answer. It is helpful to know that what I am trying to do is not possible yet with typescript.

Comment: In my real application I have a tree of field definitions, where the leafs are different types of fields. First i need to transform each leaf by wrapping them into another class (the basically the reverse of the example above), then on the resulting tree I need to invoke a more complex transformation which will result in a different output type for each different input type. The different output types have a common interface. At some point however I need to at least cast it to a more concrete definition.

Comment: I'll probably write the above up as an answer with the `unwrap()` typing example, and if you ever want to post a more concrete toy example (particular wrapping class and particular input-output mapping) I might be able to answer that too (but maybe in a new question).  Anyway I might not get to it immediately since it takes a while to write these things up.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks , you have already been very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In what follows I'm only going to worry about typings and not implementation.  All functions will just be `declare`d, as if the actual implementations are in some JS library and these are their [declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-functions).

Also, your `isLeaf` functions should probably be typed as [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) whose return type is a *type predicate* instead of just `boolean`.  A function signature `isLeaf: (value: S | Tree<S>) => value is S` is similar to one that returns `boolean`, except that the compiler will actually understand that in `if (isLeaf(x)) { x } else { x }`, the `x` in the true block will be `S` and the `x` in the false block will be `Tree<S>`.

Okay, here goes:

---

The type `Tree<X>` is too general to keep track of specific key and value types.  All the compiler knows about a value of the type, say, `Tree<string>`, is that its is an object type whose properties are either of type `string` or `Tree<string>`.  Once you do, say, this:

```
const x: Tree<string> = { a: "", b: { c: "", d: { e: "" } } };
```

You've thrown away all the details about the particular stucture as well as all the details about any specific subtypes of `string` at the leaves:

```
x.a.toUpperCase(); // error
x.z; // no error
```

If all you cared about were to come up with a type transformation that maintained the nested key structure and turned some subtype of `Tree<X>` into a subtype of `Tree<Y>` with the same shape, you could do it.  But in the most straightforward implementation, all the leaves of the resulting tree will be of type `Y` and not any narrower type.  Here's how I'd write it:

```
type TransformTree<T extends Tree<X>, X, Y> = { [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends X ? Y :
    T[K] extends Tree<X> ? TransformTree<T[K], X, Y> :
    T[K];
};
declare function transformTree<X, Y, TX extends Tree<X>>(
    obj: TX,
    transform: (value: X) => Y,
    isLeaf: (value: X | Tree<X>) => value is X
): TransformTree<TX, X, Y>;
```

And you can see it work on a simple example like this:

```
const t1 = { a: "A", b: { c: "CC", d: { e: "EEE" } } };
const t2 = transformTree(t1,
    (x: string) => x.length,
    (v): v is string => typeof v === "string"
); 
t2.a; // number
t2.b.c; // number
t2.b.d.e; // number
```

---

But you want something significantly more ambitious here; it seems like you want to have the leaf transformation map not just from a specific type `X` to a specific type `Y`, but you'd like to specify some *general type function like* `type F<T extends X> = ...` and map the leaf from type `Z extends X` to `F<Z>`.

In your example, your input type is something like `Wrapped<any>`, and your output type function would look like `type F<T extends Wrapped<any> = T["value"];`

Unfortunately, this more general type of transformation cannot be expressed in TypeScript.  You can't have a type function like `type TransformType<T extends Tree<X>, X, F> = ...` where `F` is itself a type function that takes a parameter.  That would require the language to support what's known as "higher kinded types".  There is a longstanding open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), and while it would be amazing to have them, it doesn't look like it will happen in the foreseeable future.

---

What you *can* do is envision particular types of leaf type transformations and implement specific versions of `TransformTree` for them.  For example, if your leaf type mapping just indexes into a single property like `type F<T extends Record<K, any>, K extends PropertyKey> = T[K]`, as in your `Unwrap` case, then you can write it like this:

```
type TransformTreeIdx<T, X, K extends keyof X> = { [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends X ? X[K] :
    TransformTreeIdx<T[P], X, K>;
};
declare function transformTreeIdx<TX, X, K extends keyof X>(
    obj: TX,
    key: K,
    isLeaf: (value: any) => value is X
): TransformTreeIdx<TX, X, K>;
```

And then use it:

```
const w = {
    foo: {
        bar: new Wrapper("baz" as const),
    },
    cow: new Wrapper("moo" as const),
};

const w2 = transformTreeIdx(
    w, "value", (x: any): x is Wrapper<any> => x instanceof Wrapper
);

handleBaz(w2.foo.bar);
handleMoo(w2.cow);
```

---

Or, as mentioned in your comments, you might want to do the opposite with a *particular* generic interface/class, like say, `Wrapper`... the mapping is to convert `Z extends X` into `Wrapper<Z>`:

```
type TransformTreeWrap<T, X> = { [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends X ? Wrapper<T[P]> :
    TransformTreeWrap<T[P], X>;
};
declare function transformTreeWrap<TX, X, K extends keyof X>(
    obj: TX,
    isLeaf: (value: any) => value is X
): TransformTreeWrap<TX, X>;
```

and use it:

```
const u = {
    foo: {
        bar: "baz" as const,
    },
    cow: "moo" as const,
};

const u2 = transformTreeWrap(
    u, (x: any): x is string => typeof x === "string"
);
handleBaz(u2.foo.bar.value);
handleMoo(u2.cow.value);
```

---

Or, you might have an array of `isLeaf`/`transform` pairs that allow each node to be tested against different more specific transformations.  So, for example, any time you find a `"moo"` value in the tree you output a `number` and any time you find a `"baz"` value in the tree you output a `boolean`.

Then your typings could look like:

```
type TransformTreeMap<T, M extends [any, any]> = { [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends M[0] ? Extract<M, [T[K], any]>[1] :
    TransformTreeMap<T[K], M> };

type IsLeafAndTransformer<I, O> = {
    isLeaf: (x: any) => x is I,
    transform: (x: I) => O
}
type TransformArrayToMap<M extends Array<IsLeafAndTransformer<any, any>>> = {
    [K in keyof M]: M[K] extends IsLeafAndTransformer<infer I, infer O> ?
    [I, O] : never }[number]

declare function transformTreeMap<T, M extends Array<IsLeafAndTransformer<any, any>>>(
    obj: T,
    ...transformers: M
): TransformTreeMap<T, TransformArrayToMap<M>>;
```

and you use it:

```
const mm = transformTreeMap(u,
    { isLeaf: (x: any): x is "moo" => x === "moo", transform: (x: "moo") => 123 },
    { isLeaf: (x: any): x is "baz" => x === "baz", transform: (x: "baz") => true }
);
mm.cow // number
mm.foo.bar // boolean
```

---

So there are really a lot of different and even quite powerful tree transformations you can define... just not the fully generic higher-order type implied by the question.  Hopefully one of those will give you a way forward.  Okay, good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThCAeGA+KBeKBvAsAKCiKgG0BrALigGdg4BLAOwHMBdKmKAH1gWTQDcBAL4ECAYwD2jWlAAeHPkloMW6LNigBDKgCJdAGigAjKpvF7DUACZmoES1GFOnQ-HIB0Wj8EkBVMEg4AGEtaggACgBKASgAejj7ODhJOAJPAC9YhKhGSSSUuCgxfFBIXi0ZADNUgFt4RBR7OWAIRmtqXkaADVQjbqMATXUcUgBpKCYoMggQSSrYdgJiWBIx1mbW9s7uqAB+KEGoCmXiGDWNiBa2jq7kXv2K6rqG-gv+ofQTwjOLt2E3NYIOIADZaBBQKoAV0Y4mA9GkUDolWoNTg9SUA0ORhguyuW1uryQvVQEVOREkxgAVhwBuSkXAUWjalQIgA3LQgqEOKDdKKYdCDAz0+jUAAyEC0VVZHK5PN2PCJvX5GHQsu5kx2BCiiiZLyUuI+h1Qbgk0lkwAAjJhRjooLoAIJWUyjCz24LBKy2UY83QAUQDuhczgBZpkwCRACYbcjnujXhErcKfkQIgoaHQmMwVehPCC2sxgAALZMrdk6qBszUZ1TMAVI8AQeaVzAYLC6FRZ3TatzASNebKJRhQ2rGCBpUr94wecSD3IjscTvseafWDwQOfD0fjkplaDwPXxvgASWschQRom+JunRmcwWDw0pAACpNGNNZs2YEsU6tn5drm2XlHm6C5jnpA84wxRBT3Pc5-0vE0REBYEwQhaFYXhRFY1RfUYLPFAsSxK9ANuO9m16Mlf0pGlYDpX87yoMZS2IUUJSlGVOW5KhKhAHNKy46BRV5bVdSg15YMIxDTXwUEwk6AB1RlAnHFB0DwX8pHDOAoThVIIjAKFjBBehxAEuUOH5TRRHwGytNkAB3G0NJWGpJDMekVmMcEqEYCAnKUrQVLgCJdG8jIgzCKB7OAKIWKIYR4uiyQHN8-yoEC4LQtqSRJEizoYri5CShiqAHOjLAcOZCSzyolYHKMXR1QgKw0x4xg+KoORq0yoIkF49RczfWhKnEJsFl6nd8BiEoMLhBF3yLSprHzAAhLQMnZQS9HC3QrKcAg5qwxblvzABZXKtos+0cry-abKW9o1o2iJyo8NyV3BGb8EelaIAuyRXv7KQHO+3dGyeXCj0QTKL15EZNBIV8pnIhZv2+FZ4IAgkdkeSa4BQJHWC+CDGXEvhYax-okNslC5PQmF5uwsmoegiBKaIowSJxj973huriBo2kkrYyVpSgK7uO0Dr+Oa6tulEyHqop5SpPhmSw1kKFnPpNyPN-LyfPtXbtAK81gCSxL6RBvRbvy5Lw2TUN8E1iMoQqhlDzZzKBaIKEjDa6XOvkatOxYes92bbq23bMPmG7aa3F+57Nvd97cs+uAPGa77k-+y605B7PBLBl2y4IPclbw-6grhs7NhvUheKMXjiec8Y315r8f0xsDryAs6SAABg2A4-RaRk4SQM6jBIc51hbjriZIS0Ngxs4WeVxAztr+fWCMM70GdiuIePcUxYddpINZ1TjyMAB5BGRXPjiJfTXj+O64S7-pKq6lZdMx5+L3xECfco19mQOmSFoEAMBJA7zANPBuQEoGMhAEgM+7EqiX2sBAuoqlm5B1QMQnWv41id1RlAM67AqF91Ip0TBF8r6b3wQTJgVRxxQDvm+DhRRH77HpCQbh98165AgGyThwgSBbkXKwEoQJ6bQCOgtT25Nt67wPsg24qCYEYJftg5hXsCEdUXiAYhpJ6RC1gElDwti-7onHNQKgZ1FZ4OhjXRBMAcQsPRDo2B8Da6Hxpq7KAtRagxh8WzBBER-b0k0KLV+gcP5dWrLoO29Zo5thurlKw9iWRv1tjk-ilpIwAGYnBJXifogB7Vg5f06GFDaQZVQhxjsbJpRg8k1PaRFfidANQ2W+mEmcKV4hDgXFNYZH1vJFByMYXK+ZKglCgEAA)

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that that takes an object and returns a clone with all leafs as strings:

```
function leafsToString<O extends Record<any, any>>(obj: O): unknown {
    const newObj = obj instanceof Array ? [] : Object.create(null);
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            newObj[key] = leafsToString(obj[key]);
        } else {
            newObj[key] = obj[key] + '';
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

I just need a way to type the result. So I came up with this:

```
type LeafsToString<O> = {
    [K in keyof O]:
        O[K] extends Record<any, any>
        ? LeafsToString<O[K]>
        : string
}
```

[Playground link with examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgIYILwIN4CMBcmx4DMAvgDQIAmeA2gGZIA2MApgLrEDcoksiWamXPjwByQiLKUaI%20k2Yj2HBAHplCAHRZ1YZFAoaK1AAytkAJ2YJ4ZgJZQA5jG7R4CHemx4MBBAFc9zLR2zBSSVAjUMowsCpwqapraCDYwfgFBUCGgoHAAngAOlgAyzEi0MAAqEADKcLYOADwA8gB8AhigCF0RANLJUAgA1sy5ELQITaw4nd2zTdQ9pswAHnDMeqkASsyQZhQNSFC55Ie5LTOzXQD8CCVllTV1dvbNC6znIJfdeNbPoMTZEC0fxgOA2aAIBilcpVWr1F5NBArNYbBDbXb7U4nI4tFoACggWAAVngmgBKPB3GGPeHNNodT7dHiuTIAdyaxIEhKJ-XghzAzDGCAAgmYzEhcggbtRTKTiTs4NoLEg1nioL4GAwyVxGV1aBAzAg8czEMNJUKOUSFeozTACcSyWTMBdLjZxni8oUhdzqGbTKgAwgRNyFSInQyvl82ZbfSN-ZDoQ84c97UTY7lWNqXbNiEi5M7dZGutHien4z6-QgANRBkQ6osAwuN2YWOC%20MwDEtEnWN5y8ZAodBQ%206wp4OPFILPgFwQKHqBgQex4gBS1SaADl1L8HG7chPJ2hA6uN1ux-Zd3isI6lKoEHVfMxASapLdE6PaZ7BeMkG10Egb2ozBigafauMwlJvjSzwNJ%20Qo-gIWAAQgECDKBiC0BBI5QY0sHfr%20bhIUBZgGkAA).