# Map an object and retain type inference

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function that maps an object via a map function.

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

function objectMap<TValue, TResult>(
  obj: Dictionary<TValue>,
  valSelector: (val: TValue) => TResult
) {
  const ret = {} as Dictionary<TResult>;

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    ret[key] = valSelector.call(null, obj[key]);
  }
  
  return ret;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const myObj = {
  withString: {
    api: (id: string) => Promise.resolve(id),
  },
  withNumber: {
    api: (id: number) => Promise.resolve(id),
  },
}

const mapToAPI = objectMap(myObj, (val => val.api));

mapToAPI.withString('some string');
```

There is an error produced on the last line:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

How can I map a generic object and retain type inference?

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that, but with a static key provided [it is possible](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5Klw).

Comment: eehh I doubt this is possible; it's hard to even *express* what `valSelector` should be doing without *higher kinded types* of the form requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), let alone get *inference*.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/61253397/2887218 although this one is just using a single object and not a tree structure, but the same issue with arbitrary transformations exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by jcalz, this sort of arbitrary transformation isn't possible in TS.

However if you are simply utilizing the function as a means to navigate through the tree, there are much better ways to go about it.

If you want to maintain navigability as a tree, instead of as a flat object, you can use some help from [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) as well as a utility type from [`type-fest`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/get.d.ts) to type the return value.

```js
import _ from "lodash"
import { Get } from "type-fest"

function objectMap<
  Dict extends Record<string, any>,
  Path extends string
>(
  obj: Dict,
  path: Path
): {
    [Key in keyof Dict]: Get<Dict, `${Key}.${Path}`>
} {
  const ret = {} as Record<string, any>

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    ret[key] = _.get(obj[key], path)
  }

  return ret as any
}
```

Then this will work, with no explicit typing necessary.

```js
const myObj = {
  withString: {
    api: (id: string) => Promise.resolve(id),
    wrong_api: (id: number) => Promise.resolve(id), //This is the same as withNumber.api
    similiar_api: (some_id: string) => Promise.resolve(some_id),
    remove_api: (some_id: boolean) => Promise.resolve(some_id),
    helpers: {
      help: (id: number) => {}
    }
  },
  withNumber: {
    api: (id: number) => Promise.resolve(id),
    helpers: {
      help: (id: number) => {}
    },
    not_an_api: false,
  },
}

const mapToAPI = objectMap(myObj, 'api');
const mapToAPI = objectMap(myObj, 'helpers.help');
```

And if you want type inferencing on the path to ensure only valid paths, you can use another utility function, a recursive one to convert the object nodes to a union of all strings, although this only built to work on objects, and will probably explode on arrays. It will also explode and throw `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite` if you have a large enough object, hence why it wasn't included originally.

```js
import { UnionToIntersection } from "type-fest";

type UnionForAny<T> = T extends never ? 'A' : 'B';

type IsStrictlyAny<T> = UnionToIntersection<UnionForAny<T>> extends never
  ? true
  : false;

export type AcceptablePaths<Node, Stack extends string | number = ''> = 
  IsStrictlyAny<Node> extends true ? `${Stack}` :
  Node extends Function ? `${Stack}` :
  Node extends Record<infer Key, infer Item> 
    ? Key extends number | string 
      ? Stack extends ''
        ? `${AcceptablePaths<Item, Key>}`
        : `${Stack}.${AcceptablePaths<Item, Key>}`
      : ''
    : ''
```

For something finally, like this

```js
function objectMap<
  Dict extends Record<string, any>,
  Path extends AcceptablePaths<Dict[keyof Dict]>,
>(
  obj: Dict,
  path: Path
): 
{
    [Key in keyof Dict]: Get<Dict, `${Key}.${Path}`>
} {/** Implementation from above **/}
```

View this on [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-xs2p40)

Answer (score 0):

The following is mostly based on @kellys' comment and requires the type `K` to be explicit if other properties are present, but it seems to work:

```
function objectMap<T, K extends keyof T[keyof T]>(
  obj: T,
  valSelector: (o: T[keyof T]) => T[keyof T][K],
): {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P][K];
} {
  const ret = {} as {
      [P in keyof T]: T[P][K];
  };

  for (const key of Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[]) {
    ret[key] = valSelector(obj[key]);
  }
  
  return ret;
}

const myObj = {
  withString: {
    api: (id: string) => Promise.resolve(id),
    bea: "ciao",
  },
  withNumber: {
    api: (id: number) => Promise.resolve(id),
    bea: 123
  },
}

const mapToAPI = objectMap<typeof myObj, "api">(myObj, val => val.api);

mapToAPI.withString('some string');
mapToAPI.withNumber(123)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHARgKwKbQLIEMAOAPACoA0iA0ohgB5QZgAmAzogNYYCecwixA2h269iAXQB8ACgCwAKETJ0ALj6k5CgG64ANgGUM2rFDgAnFZLgqBQnn1EBKRAF5xfQV1tj+FUWtn2VAG91BUR+AAVEGCQbEVErCNFvUQBuOQBfRGD5RAgEZihEEwxCpyzM3FZs0NCIqJiPOITwpJ80nPT2kOBTREk8sAL2LmReAHl0IwA6IWYLdEdKvti+e34HLJCFYqh3TlFnRC09AyNTebQ9h3aFdJCQnZATJB32u9k5AaGAW04JtEO1UQAHcYFAABa6KAmaIAcyCW0QBBg5hgjBUBRhYFhjhciHCJjg3xgzAwU2KzDg2g0GEkaPsfhqKAwuBUACIIDBcHA2YzEOk+aCIQA5EDfZlmTY5BTI1HoxBgMUS3GuAlEklkilUml0xgMxHM1mIACMACYAMwhAUZOSffKFb4EYhwACC4QAkodUJgcARCFBOPgMLZfv9yGzkWypKH0ORjs5XMcpsj7F1ZI78M63e6pkLIdC4ZIAOSU74YRCYuFF1NyDNZj25sHg0XijAmSRm832IA)

Maybe someone is able to further improve it.